# creating Kubernetes POD with DeletionGracePeriodSeconds is not respected

Tags: go, kubernetes

I am creating Kubernetes POD with Golang. Iam trying to set DeletionGracePeriodSeconds but after creating pod, the pod has 30 in this field while I am setting 25.
Name of the pod is OK, so after creating the POD it has name that I assigned in code.

```
func setupPod(client *Client, ns string, name string, labels map[string]string) (*v1.Pod, error) {
     seconds := func(i int64) *int64 { return &i }(25)
     pod := &v1.Pod{}
     pod.Name = name
     pod.Namespace = ns
     pod.SetDeletionGracePeriodSeconds(seconds) //it is 25 seconds under debugger
     pod.DeletionGracePeriodSeconds = seconds
     pod.Spec.Containers = []v1.Container{v1.Container{Name: "ubuntu", Image: "ubuntu", Command: []string{"sleep", "30"}}}
     pod.Spec.NodeName = "node1"
     if labels != nil {
        pod.Labels = labels
     }
     _, err := client.client.CoreV1().Pods(ns).Create(client.context, pod, metav1.CreateOptions{})
     return pod, err
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DeletionGracePeriodSeconds` is read-only and hence you can not change it. You should instead set `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` and kubernetes will set the `DeletionGracePeriodSeconds` accordingly. You can verify that by getting the value and printing it.

From the [API docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/)

> Number of seconds allowed for this object to gracefully terminate
> before it will be removed from the system. Only set when
> deletionTimestamp is also set. May only be shortened. **Read-only**.

```
podSpec := &v1.Pod{
        Spec: v1.PodSpec{
            TerminationGracePeriodSeconds: <Your-Grace-Period>
        },
    }

    _, err = clientset.CoreV1().Pods("namespacename").Create(context.TODO(), podSpec, metav1.CreateOptions{})
```

Comment: thanks, where did u find the informaction how to do that :)

Comment: You can search for `DeletionGracePeriodSeconds` here https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/